# What is the best way to create mapping from SQL database to GUI?

Tags: sql, user-interface, mapping

I think its quite usual task, but still solutions I saw look not so nice.

For example in Qt used approach based on MVC pattern -- you must assign all connections manually.
Or I remember one PHP engine where pages were creating from DB schema.

Which are other approaches? Which one you are prefer? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is not a one to one mapping from the database to the GUIThere are many subtle combinations that change between how you store the data and how that stored data is visualized and edited by the user.

however, you can automate a datamodel layer in your code with tools like Hibernate.  You will still need to use the model as required to present your user interface.